# How can I get smart card Provider ID in windows xp using dot net

Tags: smartcard

I am using c# for developing smart card apps
I need to get the smart card provider ID
I am trying to use SCardGetProviderId

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public static extern SCardErr SCardGetProviderId(IntPtr hContext, string szCard,ref _GUID guid);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct _GUID
{
        long Data1;
        short Data2;
        short Data3;
        string Data4;
}
```

but nothing is being returned in the GUID struct 
I dont know how to get the smart card name??

How can i get the smart card name ???

Answer (score 0):

With my (Omnikey) smart card reader a tool was provided, which shows up in Windows settings. It shows the state of the reader, whether a card is inserted and if so, the ATR, card name and selected communication protocol.